# Problem on launching Activity from other application

Tags: android, launchmode

I have met a problem, hope you can provide some suggestion on it.

Here is the problem:

There is an `A` Activity in my application which is the application's `MAIN` Activity, and can be started from other application(like SMS). Consider now there are `A-B-C-D` activities in my application's task, as I said before, user can start `A` Activity from SMS, when `A` is launched from SMS, I want `B C D` all to be finished, and the instance of `A` Activity in the task will be brought to front.

I tried to set `A` activity's `launchMode` to `singleTask`, this will do the trick, but there is another problem: for example, I got `A-B-C-D` Activities in my application's task, user press `HOME` key to the home screen, and **re-launch** the application from the launcher, then `A` Activity is shown instead of `D` Activity. It's like the application have been started from the beginning, that is not what I want.

Is there any way that I can do this? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case, you already have `A-B-C-D`, and `A` is launched by SMS, without setting `launchMode` to `singleTask`, what happens?

Comment: @Rajath An new instance of `A` Activity will be created and started. User will see `A` Activity, when press `BACK` key, the SMS application will be shown. So, I think there are two task in my application, which are `A-B-C-D` and `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but you can try this:

1. Set the activity attribute [alwaysRetainTaskState](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#always) to true.
   This should take care to retain all the activities in the stack.
2. When you want the root activity to be shown (In your case : when launched from SMS - I assume you are invoking the activity from your SMS receiver using start activity), in the intent you pass to startActivity set the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) flag.
   This should clear off since you explicitly mention it in the Intent.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I have tried, but it cannot work as what I want, here are the results:  1, I tried setting `launchMode` to `singleTask` and `alwaysRetainTaskState` to `true`, it worked just like what I desribed in my question. It seems that `alwaysRetainTaskState` will only work when user hasn't visited the app after a long time.  2, Sorry about that I haven't described my problem clear enough, `A` Activity is not started in an `BroadcastReceiver`, but by system, since I add a `<intent-filter>` in `<activity>` which contains `ACTION_VIEW` action and `<data host="my.host.com">`.